How would I only include tickets with certain status in PHP
I have two files. In table.php, I've implemented the display logic for data retrieved from our database. My objective within index.php is to include table.php while selectively filtering tickets based on their status, specifically, those with a status of "OPEN."
I've tried to modify sql query in the table.php and include in the index.php like thisinclude table.php=?status=Open; but this did not work infact in produced errors. 
How would I approach this? Is it possible to modify include like I've tried?
Here is the table.php code:
<?php

include 'menu.php';
include 'connection.php';

// Retrieve user's location using functions from location.php
require_once 'location.php';
$locationName = $locations[$n];

// Set default sorting parameters
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'title';
$sort = isset($_GET['sort']) && ($_GET['sort'] === 'DESC' || $_GET['sort'] === 'ASC') ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC';

// Toggle sorting direction
$newSort = ($sort === 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

// Retrieve status filter
$statusFilter = isset($_GET['status']) ? $_GET['status'] : null;

// Query to retrieve all tickets from the database
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tickets ORDER BY $order $sort");

// Filter tickets to include only those with status 'Open'
$statusFilter = 'Open'; // Set the status filter to 'Open' for open tickets
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE status = '$statusFilter'";

// Check if user is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    // User is logged in, retrieve department ID
    $departmentID = $_SESSION['department_id'];
    if ($departmentID == 0) {
        // Retrieve tickets for admin user
        $sql = "SELECT tickets.id_ticket, tickets.name, tickets.location, tickets.priority, departments.department_name, tickets.title, tickets.creation_date, tickets.status, tickets.update_date, COUNT(files.file_id) AS FileCount
                FROM tickets
                INNER JOIN departments ON tickets.department_id = departments.department_id
                LEFT JOIN files ON tickets.id_ticket = files.ticket_id
                WHERE tickets.hidden = 0
                GROUP BY tickets.id_ticket
                ORDER BY tickets.title ASC";

    } else {
        // Retrieve tickets for non-admin user
        $sql = "SELECT tickets.id_ticket, tickets.name, tickets.location, tickets.priority, departments.department_name, tickets.title, tickets.creation_date, tickets.status, tickets.update_date, COUNT(files.file_id) AS FileCount
                FROM tickets
                INNER JOIN departments ON tickets.department_id = departments.department_id
                LEFT JOIN files ON tickets.id_ticket = files.ticket_id
                WHERE tickets.department_id = $departmentID AND tickets.hidden = 0
                GROUP BY tickets.id_ticket
                ORDER BY $order $sort";
    }
} else {
    // User is not logged in, retrieve tickets by location only
    $sql = "SELECT tickets.id_ticket, tickets.name, tickets.location, tickets.priority, departments.department_name, tickets.title, tickets.creation_date, tickets.status, tickets.update_date, COUNT(files.file_id) AS FileCount
            FROM tickets
            INNER JOIN departments ON tickets.department_id = departments.department_id
            LEFT JOIN files ON tickets.id_ticket = files.ticket_id
            WHERE tickets.location = '$locationName' AND tickets.hidden = 0
            GROUP BY tickets.id_ticket
            ORDER BY $order $sort";
}

// Execute SQL query
$result = $conn->query($sql);
...
?>

Code for index.php:
 <body>
        <?php

        $statusFilter = 'Open';

        include 'ticket_table.php?status=' . $statusFilter;
        ?>


Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

@Dharman even if this is used inside a closed group (small company) I should still prepare statements?

Yes, there is absolutely no reason to ever have an excuse for not using prepared statements.

a quick solution is to retrieve the content of the page with file_get_contents() :
$content = file_get_contents('ticket_table.php?status=' . $statusFilter);
echo $content ;

Another solution (and maybe better in the long term) is to put the view logic in a separated file/class, and let both index.php and table.php call this unique resource.
index.php:
require_once 'DataViewer.php';
$content = (new DataViewer($statusFiler))->render();
echo $content ;

table.php:
require_once 'DataViewer.php';
/* stuff with $_GET variables */
$content = (new DataViewer($statusFilter))->render();
echo $content ;


Yes. I solved my issue by creating new file and inserting table structure in it while I let the query in ticket_table remain there and added new query in index.php that fetches only tickets with "Open" status. Your answer kinda gave me an idea on what I want to do.

Passing a querystring to an include doesn't work. You can do this:
index.php
<h1>INDEX 1</h1>
<?php
$_REQUEST['status'] = 'Open';

 include 'table.php';
 ?>

table.php
<?php

echo $_REQUEST['status'];

